# A question regarding a particular space

Tags: functional-analysis

I have a question regarding the notation of a space that I came across in a book. What is the definition of $C^0(X, Y)$, where $X$ and $Y$ and normed spaces?

Comment: What is the book?

Comment: Maybe it denotes the set of all the continuous mappings from $X$ to $Y$.

Answer (score 1):

It's the standard notation (in French, at least!) for the set of continuous functions from $X$ to $Y$. It's often written simply as $\mathcal{C}(X,Y)$.